# Worklight 6.2 Authentication to LDAP using OpenDS

Tags: authentication, ldap, ibm-mobilefirst, local, opends

I am struggling to get ldap authentication using openDS to work. I am using Worklight Studio 6.2 and Apache DS 2.0 as the ldap browser.

The project is supposed to call a login page, and then submit the username and password for authentication to ldap.

I get the following error in the firefox console:

```
POST http://x.x.x.x:10080/LDAPTest/apps/services/j_security_check [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 253ms]
undefined entity j_security_check:134
```

And in eclipse in the worklight console:

```
[WARNING ] FWLSE0138W: LdapLoginModule authentication failed. Reason 'javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
[WARNING ] FWLSE0239W: Authentication failure in realm 'LDAPRealm': login fail [project LDAPTest]
```

I thought that the issue would be either my connection string or my challange handler. But I suspect that since my errror is invalid credentials that it must be my connection string in the authenticationconfig.xml.

I have tried several methods including some of the posts here such as :

[Worklight LDAP authentication using ApacheDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287087/worklight-ldap-authentication-using-apacheds)
[Worklight LDAP authentication using ApacheDS 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387441/worklight-ldap-authentication-using-apacheds-2-0)

and there others. I followed the IBM LDAP sample to set this up and I have checked to make sure that I have the same structure.

Any help figuring this out would be much appreciated. Also if you think I should check my LDAP config, I can post that too I followed a tutorial from  openDS wiki. I was able to connect to it using apache browser studio and softera LDAP administrator.

My project is as follows:-

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>LDAPTest</title>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
            -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
</head>
<body style="display: none;">

    <div id="header">
        <h1>SigmaLDAP Login Module</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="AppDiv">
            <input type="button" class="appButton"
                value="Call protected adapter proc" onclick="getSecretData()" /> <input
                type="button" class="appButton" value="Logout"
                onclick="WL.Client.logout('LDAPRealm',{onSuccess: WL.Client.reloadApp})" />
            <p id="resultDiv"></p>
        </div>

        <div id="AuthDiv" style="display: none">
            <div id="loginForm">
                <input type="text" id="usernameInputField"
                    placeholder="Enter username" /> <br /> <input type="password"
                    placeholder="Enter password" id="passwordInputField" /> <br /> <input
                    type="button" class="formButton" id="loginButton" value="Login" />
                <input type="button" class="formButton" id="cancelButton"
                    value="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    <script src="js/LDAPRealmChallenger.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Main.js**

```
function wlCommonInit(){

}

function getSecretData(){
    WL.Logger.info('invoking the adpater');
    var invocationData = {
            adapter: "LDAPter",
            procedure: "getSecretData",
            parameters: []
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess: getSecretData_Callback,
        onFailure: getSecretData_Callback,
        timeout: 2000
    });
}

function getSecretData_Callback(response){
    $("#resultDiv").css("padding", "10px");
    $("#resultDiv").html(new Date() + "<hr/>");
    $("#resultDiv").append("Secret data :: " + response.invocationResult.secretData + "<hr/>"); 
    $("#resultDiv").append("Response :: " + JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

**My Challenger.js**

```
var LDAPRealmChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("LDAPRealm");

LDAPRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
    if (!response || !response.responseText) {
        WL.Logger.info('failed to authenticate');
    }

    var idx = response.responseText.indexOf("j_security_check");

    if (idx >= 0){ 
        WL.Logger.info("Authenticated");
        return true;
    }
    return false;

};

LDAPRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response){
        $('#AppDiv').hide();
        $('#AuthDiv').show();
        $('#passwordInputField').val('');
};

$('#loginButton').bind('click', function () {
    var reqURL = '/j_security_check';
    var options = {};
    options.parameters = {
            j_username : $('#usernameInputField').val(),
            j_password : $('#passwordInputField').val()
    };
    options.headers = {};
    LDAPRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginForm(reqURL, options, LDAPRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback);
});

$('#cancelButton').bind('click', function () {
    $('#AppDiv').show();
    $('#AuthDiv').hide();
    LDAPRealmChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
});

LDAPRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback = function(response) {
    var isLoginFormResponse = LDAPRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse(response);
    if (isLoginFormResponse){
        LDAPRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge(response);
    } else {
        $('#AppDiv').show();
        $('#AuthDiv').hide();
        LDAPRealmChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
    }
};
```

**My adpater:** 
 **the js file**

```
function getSecretData(){
     console.log("getting you secrets mofos");
    return {secretData: 1234};
  }
```

**The xml file:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--
        Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
        5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
        US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
        disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
    -->
    <wl:adapter name="LDAPter"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
        xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http">

        <displayName>LDAPter</displayName>
        <description>LDAPter</description>
            <connectivity>
            <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
                <protocol>http</protocol>
                <domain>none</domain>
                <port>80</port>         
            </connectionPolicy>
            <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
        </connectivity>

        <procedure name="getSecretData"  securityTest="LDAPSecurityTest" />
    </wl:adapter>


The authenticationConfig.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:loginConfiguration xmlns:tns="http://www.worklight.com/auth/config"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM 5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 
        2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved. US Government Users Restricted Rights - 
        Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with 
        IBM Corp. -->

    <staticResources>
        <!-- <resource id="logUploadServlet" securityTest="LogUploadServlet"> <urlPatterns>/apps/services/loguploader*</urlPatterns> 
            </resource> -->
        <resource id="subscribeServlet" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
            <urlPatterns>/subscribeSMS*;/receiveSMS*;/ussd*</urlPatterns>
        </resource>

    </staticResources>

    <!-- Sample security tests Even if not used there will be some default webSecurityTest 
        and mobileSecurityTest Attention: If you are adding an app authenticity realm 
        to a security test, you must also update the application-descriptor.xml. 
        Please refer to the user documentation on application authenticity for environment 
        specific guidelines. -->

    <securityTests>

        <customSecurityTest name="LDAPSecurityTest">
                <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="LDAPRealm" />
        </customSecurityTest>

        <!-- <mobileSecurityTest name="mobileTests"> <testAppAuthenticity/> <testDeviceId 
            provisioningType="none" /> <testUser realm="myMobileLoginForm" /> <testDirectUpdate 
            mode="perSession" /> </mobileSecurityTest> <webSecurityTest name="webTests"> 
            <testUser realm="myWebLoginForm"/> </webSecurityTest> <customSecurityTest 
            name="customTests"> <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/> <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" 
            step="1"/> <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/> <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" 
            mode="perSession" step="1"/> <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" 
            step="1"/> <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" 
            step="2"/> </customSecurityTest> <customSecurityTest name="LogUploadServlet"> 
            <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" step="1"/> <test realm="LogUploadServlet" 
            isInternalUserID="true"/> </customSecurityTest> -->
        <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
            <test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true" />
        </customSecurityTest>

    </securityTests>

    <realms>

        <realm loginModule="LDAPLoginModule" name="LDAPRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
            <onLoginUrl>/console</onLoginUrl>
        </realm>

        <realm name="SubscribeServlet" loginModule="rejectAll">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>
        </realm>

        <!-- For client logger -->
        <!-- <realm name="LogUploadServlet" loginModule="StrongDummy"> <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className> 
            </realm -->

        <!-- For websphere -->
        <!-- realm name="WASLTPARealm" loginModule="WASLTPAModule"> <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereFormBasedAuthenticator</className> 
            <parameter name="login-page" value="/login.html"/> <parameter name="error-page" 
            value="/loginError.html"/> </realm -->

        <!-- For User Certificate Authentication -->
        <!-- realm name="wl_userCertificateAuthRealm" loginModule="WLUserCertificateLoginModule"> 
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateAuthenticator</className> 
            <parameter name="dependent-user-auth-realm" value="WASLTPARealm" /> <parameter 
            name="pki-bridge-class" value="com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateEmbeddedPKI" 
            /> <parameter name="embedded-pki-bridge-ca-p12-file-path" value="/opt/ssl_ca/ca.p12"/> 
            <parameter name="embedded-pki-bridge-ca-p12-password" value="capassword" 
            /> </realm -->

        <!-- For Trusteer Fraud Detection -->
        <!-- Requires acquiring Trusteer SDK -->
        <!-- realm name="wl_basicTrusteerFraudDetectionRealm" loginModule="trusteerFraudDetectionLogin"> 
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.TrusteerAuthenticator</className> 
            <parameter name="rooted-device" value="block"/> <parameter name="device-with-malware" 
            value="block"/> <parameter name="rooted-hiders" value="block"/> <parameter 
            name="unsecured-wifi" value="alert"/> <parameter name="outdated-configuration" 
            value="alert"/> </realm -->

    </realms>

    <loginModules>

        <loginModule name="LDAPLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule</className>
            <parameter name="ldapProviderUrl" value="ldap://localhost:389/dc=sigma,dc=com" />
            <parameter name="ldapTimeoutMs" value="2000"/>
            <parameter name="ldapSecurityAuthentication" value="simple"/>
            <parameter name="validationType" value="searchPattern"/>
            <parameter name="ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern" value="uid={username},ou=users,dc=sigma,dc=com"/>
            <parameter name="ldapSearchFilterPattern" value="(uid={username})"/>
            <parameter name="ldapSearchBase" value="ou=users,dc=sigma,dc=com"/>  
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="StrongDummy">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="requireLogin">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="rejectAll">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <!-- Required for Trusteer - wl_basicTrusteerFraudDetectionRealm -->
        <!-- loginModule name="trusteerFraudDetectionLogin"> <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.TrusteerLoginModule</className> 
            </loginModule -->

        <!-- For websphere -->
        <!-- loginModule name="WASLTPAModule"> <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereLoginModule</className> 
            </loginModule -->

        <!-- Login module for User Certificate Authentication -->
        <!-- <loginModule name="WLUserCertificateLoginModule"> <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateLoginModule</className> 
            </loginModule> -->


        <!-- For enabling SSO with no-provisioning device authentication -->
        <!-- <loginModule name="MySSO" ssoDeviceLoginModule="WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule"> 
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className> 
            </loginModule> -->


        <!-- For enabling SSO with auto-provisioning device authentication -->
        <!-- <loginModule name="MySSO" ssoDeviceLoginModule="WLDeviceAutoProvisioningLoginModule"> 
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className> 
            </loginModule> -->
    </loginModules>

</tns:loginConfiguration>
```

The response from the j_security_check

```
Request URL:    http://x.x.x.x:10080/LDAPTest/apps/services/j_security_check
Request Method:     POST
Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 200 OK


Request Headers 12:47:00.000
x-wl-app-version:   1.0
x-wl-analytics-tracking-id: a948e425-1ace-a28b-3d27-11bac5ba3de3
X-Requested-With:   XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Referer:    http://10.2.38.14:10080/LDAPTest/apps/services/preview/LDAPTest/common/0/default/index.html
Pragma: no-cache
Host:   10.2.38.14:10080
Content-Type:   application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 37
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Accept-Language:    en-US
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*


Sent Cookie
WL_PERSISTENT_COOKIE:   b24de65a-9c5a-4f58-97d7-348e92c78034
testcookie: oreo
LtpaToken2: rZBXVP4XKLnpvJpLFrp3UArtZGrcsGAXr4jGDTBurns9Ej5Nrx1s4/yWsDJJN6xfWkxWh1/3bBruHvL9twdae1qVcE2/D/0GfMwd1pVLbpowclNLFtqKBonEXxV6TlFIVaKgKz62SHR2to3Az/vbTjF+ZH8V1QnAdGi6dC8mk+wympju0P/4hLKWHseN9Sty2UM94cL2Cd+vcBGhJ5QVF211RIwQTXuGeQl+WMTg6B8Kfjlvly4sanyVr5va2AW38752VNEWtdnsrTHcayO/lAG1SyebFEKtaTVZhOPBkml5m6AojEGlDbcUjjof6e9H
JSESSIONID: 0000QTvrT7OBSgjn7OJG9XPMtIE:b45f2ac7-fb59-4da4-b233-f8bc81b81cf0


Response Headers Δ315ms
X-Powered-By:   Servlet/3.0
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
P3P:    policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"
Expires:    -1
Date:   Mon, 10 Nov 2014 11:47:00 GMT
Content-Language:   en-US
```

And the firefox console also returns undefined entity for j_sescurity_check and a line number 134, which in the snippet below is the last line before the dic. 
The code it points to is as follows:

```
body onload="isPopup(); setFocus();">
        <div id="authenticatorLoginFormWrapper">
            <h1>IBM</h1>
            <h2>IBM Worklight</h2>
            <form method="post" action="j_security_check">
                <p id="error">Please check the credentials</p>
                <label for="j_username">User name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" placeholder="User name" />
                <br />
                <label for="j_password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" placeholder="Password" />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Log In" />
            </form>
            <p id="copyright">&copy; 2006, 2012 IBM Corporation. <a href="#" target="_blank">Trademark</a></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything immediately wrong. Could you post the contents of the response for POST http://x.x.x.x:10080/LDAPTest/apps/services/j_security_check? There may be a hidden error there that the challenge handler does not handle.

Comment: Sorry for the late response Mike, please find the contents of the j_security_check added as an edit above. I didn't find anything useful in it. I have been playing around with my connection string trying to figure out if that where the issue is but nothing definitive yet

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and eliminate some variables in your setup and try as a first step to check whether your LDAP server is configured properly?

you can use this: https://serverfault.com/questions/514870/how-do-i-authenticate-with-ldap-via-the-command-line

to do a simple connection to your ldap server using a command line tool

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and a working config in my case was to move from `simple` to `exists` check in the `authenticationConfig.xml` file. 
But especially the big leap forward was not using the `uid` anymore in the `ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern` and instead use `cn` for the user.

I paste the configuration below hoping it's useful for you (please note in my specific case I setup a test server corp.workgroup.com domain):

```
 <loginModules>
  <loginModule expirationInSeconds="-1" name="LDAPLoginModule">
  <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule</className>
   <parameter name="ldapProviderUrl" value="ldap://yourserver" />
   <parameter name="ldapTimeoutMs" value="2000" />
   <parameter name="ldapSecurityAuthentication" value="simple" />
   <parameter name="validationType" value="exists" />
   <parameter name="ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern" value="cn={username},cn=Users,dc=corp,dc=workgroup,dc=com" />
   <parameter name="ldapReferral" value="ignore" />
</loginModule>
```